# React.js what is the "ctx" object and where does it come from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seen the dubious "ctx" object in React sometimes as a parameter, like in this _app.js:
https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/fetch-data-once-in-app-js~d76c5ea2-1a6f-4719-b476-a05765c726d1

and I am wondering what it exactly is and where does it come from, as I have seen no good documentation about what it is... is it the same as props passed to some react component?

Comment: `ctx` is context object which is passed to `getInitialProps` [`Ref`](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ctx` is a [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/) artifact. It is not part of standard React.

`ctx` is a context object containing those properties ([Source](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle)):

- `pathname` - path section of URL
- `query` - query string section of URL parsed as an object
- `asPath` - String of the actual path (including the query) shows in the browser
- `req` - HTTP request object (server only)
- `res` - HTTP response object (server only)
- `err` - Error object if any error is encountered during the rendering

[This](https://medium.com/@griko/exploring-undocumented-getinitialprops-properties-on-next-js-1265a6abc652) may also help you.